# lighttpd compilation for ARM architecture

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, lighttpd

i'm trying to install lighttpd in linux (UBUNTU) and cross compile it to ARM architecture, so could anyone perhaps help me with the possible ./configure step, i'm mentioning the steps i've done till now. -

1.wget https://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/releases-1.4.x/lighttpd-1.4.66.tar.gz

2.tar xvzf lighttpd-1.4.66.tar.gz

3. ./configure --build=arm-linux-gnueabi
4. make

but i want the possibility of ./configure step in this form - "./configure --host=arm-dey-linux-gnueabi --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/"

Comment: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/InstallFromSource If you're building from source, you should use the latest lighttpd release, currently lighttpd 1.4.69

Comment: The *general* answer to your question on how to build lighttpd is to find the answer in the official lighttpd documentation.  I gave that answer to the new poster because starting with documentation at the primary source is *generally* a good place to start.

I realize that stackoverflow thinks cut-n-paste into stackoverflow is "always" what stackoverflow wants, but I disagree that such is "always" the best thing to do.

The editors helpfully converted my answer into a comment, so you can find the link to the primary source of the documentation above.